# Get recent documents from OneDrive with Microsoft Api Graph [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on an API which lists the 10th last documents on OneDrive in nodeJS. I know I can have this information by calling Microsoft API Graph with "drive/me" but it must have an
 application ID to call the web service. I want to call the service with only Office authentification and not using application ID because it's not possible in my company.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your application with MS App Registration Portal [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) to get an application id, which is needed for your application to communicate to MS Graph API.

The users of your application will still use MS Office 365 user name and password to be authenticated to get data from Office 365.

Both of these are two entirely different things.

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply, but i said i can't register my app on MS Registration portal because it's impossible in my company, that's why i said i only want to use Authentification with Office (Login/Password) to communicate to MS Graph API.

Comment: It's impossible to use MS Graph API in your code without registering your application with Microsoft. It's like you want to withdraw money from a bank but don't want to open an account with that bank.

Comment: just wanted to clarify, registering your app on MS App Reg Portal does not mean you are "hosting" your app there. It simply creates an ID and secret for your app to include in MS Graph API calls. You can host your app anywhere. I don't think any company policy comes into effect in this case.